# do python custom linked-lists carry all their attributes in each node?

Tags: python, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to translate a [Python voronoi diagram generator](https://github.com/jansonh/Voronoi/blob/master/DataType.py) into Java. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how the Arc class works.

I've implemented linked lists in Java before, but the implementation here seems very different from what I'm used to. I'm not completely sure it is a linked list, it just seems like it because of the way the class is used later on.

*Does the Arc class here carry all it's attributes in each node?*

**The Arc class:**

```
class Arc:
    p = None     
    pprev = None 
    pnext = None 
    e = None
    s0 = None
    s1 = None

    def __init__(self, p, a=None, b=None):
        self.p = p
        self.pprev = a
        self.pnext = b
        self.e = None
        self.s0 = None
        self.s1 = None
```

**Example of Arc class in use:**

```
def process_event(self):
    # get next event from circle pq
    e = self.event.pop()

    if e.valid:
        # start new edge
        s = Segment(e.p)
        self.output.append(s)

        # remove associated arc (parabola)
        a = e.a  # <-- a is an "Arc" type
        if a.pprev is not None:
            a.pprev.pnext = a.pnext
            a.pprev.s1 = s
        if a.pnext is not None:
            a.pnext.pprev = a.pprev
            a.pnext.s0 = s

        # finish the edges before and after a
        if a.s0 is not None: a.s0.finish(e.p)
        if a.s1 is not None: a.s1.finish(e.p)

        # recheck circle events on either side of p
        if a.pprev is not None: self.check_circle_event(a.pprev, e.x)
        if a.pnext is not None: self.check_circle_event(a.pnext, e.x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a mild nomenclature confusion in your question, but as long as I understand it correctly and for given example, the short answer is: yes.

Assuming by node you mean each instance of `Arc` type object, as constructed in the first snippet, all attributes are bound to an instance (and for that matter at least from this code) defining them also as class attributes above does not seem to serve any particular purpose or make a lot of sense.

Comment: Thank you! I agree the way they are defined is strange. The Python implementation itself is taken from a C++ implementation [here](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~mbrubeck/voronoi.html).

Comment: I admit to not have any context for the code itself, but usually when I see something like that, I tend to suspect other language influences/habits to be involved. :)